# Verilog array of different sized vectors

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vector, verilog, system-verilog

I have a problem that requires converging wires down in stages, where each stage has half as many inputs and outputs as the previous one (think similar to staged selectors). I don't want to have unconnected wires in my module.

Can I declare an array of size numStages of vectors, and then define the size of each vector in a generate loop? For example:

```
module Log2Alg(x, a, b);
    parameter N = 1;
    localparam numStages = $clog2(N);
    output x;
    input [N-1:0] a, b;
    wire [???] stageInputs [0:numStages-1];
    wire [???] stageOutputs [0:numStages-1];

    genvar i, j;
    generate
        for(i = 0; i < numStages; i = i + 1)
        begin: generateStage
            stageInputs[i] = [2**(N-i):0]; // ???
            stageOutputs[i+1] = [2**(N-i-1)-1:0] // ???

            // Do stuff. Loop over j = i**2-1:0
        end
    endgenerate

endmodule
```

Is there another approach I should be considering, or a way to accomplish what I am attempting?

Comment: Why not define the wires inside generate block? So that you can adjust the wire dimensions and you can access if as if it was an array. (E.g. `generateStage[3].stageInputs`)

Comment: Can you merge 2 output wires of a stage or all outputs are different? And how many stages do u have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the declarations of your wires into the `generate` loop instead of making them arrays.

```
module Log2Alg #(N=1) (
    output x, 
    input [N-1:0] a, b
    );
    localparam numStages = $clog2(N);


    genvar i, j;
    generate
        for(i = 0; i < numStages; i = i + 1)
        begin: generateStage
        wire stageInputs [2**(N-i):0];
        wire stageOutputs [2**(N-i-1)-1:0];
            // Do _stuff_. Loop over j = i**2-1:0
            //
        end
    endgenerate

endmodule
```

Then if you need to access wires in a different stage from the current *stuff*, you can use something like `generateStage[i+1].stageInputs`. The index you use access `generateStage` must be a constant because it's not really an array of identical elements.

Comment: Follow up question: Is there any way I could create or access an implicit generateStage[-1]?

Comment: You can start the generate loop at -1. You can also put conditional generates around the _stuff_ code.